# Undo (ctrl +z ) is not working for text area when I use jquery autocomplete in IE

Tags: jquery-autocomplete

Jquery autocomplete breaks the undo in IE, In case of textarea what may be the reason ?

Try this,

Open this link in IE

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple

Type any text in input element, for example type 'a' select 'ActionScript' from menu
now do backpsace to remove characters.

Now do undo ctrl + z , It's not working why ?
can any one explain ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem:

[Html text input undo not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849864/html-text-input-undo-not-working)

In the end I found out that if any JavaScript updated any visual elements, all the text boxes on the page had their undo history reset. In my case it was a timer updating a countdown clock, which made it very difficult to trace and debug. I imagine it is the autocomplete JQuery causing the problem here. The difference to mine is that it is updating the actual textbox, not an external element, but I suspect it is the same issue. I'm pretty sure it's a bug in IE so there's not a lot you can do about it, short of adding your own history functionality to the text box.

This is a problem specific to Internet Explorer - I suggest you try your page with Chrome or Firefox.