# Html text input undo not working

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer, textbox, undo

I'm having a problem where the undo function (both ctrl+z and right click > undo) of html text boxes and text areas is being disabled. This is happening on pages generated from ASP.NET, and which incorporate a lot of Silverlight, JavaScript, JQuery and Ajax. It happens about 90% of the time, 10% of the time the undo works OK. It only happens when viewing the page in IE (8 + 9), it works fine in Chrome, Opera and Firefox.

It's not really practical for me to post the code on here, as there is so much of it and the problem could be burried deep anywhere in it. I'm more wondering if anyone had come across this before, or if it is a known issue. Can anyone suggest anything that might point me in the right direction?

Comment: similar problem here, might be jquery? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846516/undo-ctrl-z-is-not-working-for-text-area-when-i-use-jquery-autocomplete-in-i sadly, no answers as yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you got any JS timers on the page.  Even if they don't update the particular controls they can cause the control history to be wiped.  I suspect it's a bug in IE.

Comment: Yes, JS times were updating other controllers on the page. If I take them out it works OK!