# The difference between the runtime behavior [jQuery $(selector).Append('something')] in IE and GoogleChrome

Tags: jquery, html

When I run the code below in Chrome, when you type something in the text area, you can undo your typing with `Ctrl+Z`. In IE, for some reason, you can't. You can if I don't hook the `keyup` event, but with the `keyup` event hooked up as below, you can't. Does anyone know why not and whether I can do anything about it?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(function(){
                jQuery("#hoge").bind("keyup", function(){
                    jQuery("#fuga").append("fugaA!!");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="hoge"></textarea>
        <div id="fuga"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

- [JSBin with event hooked up](http://jsbin.com/unawus/1)
- [JSBin *without* the event hooked up](http://jsbin.com/unawus/2) (so you can see that `Ctrl+Z` works on IE if there's no `keyup` handler)

Comment: I am sorry. Not good at English, I had become confusing.
"Append" event after the execution, the focus is still being hit the textarea, I am not able to UNDO what was previously entered on the textarea.

Comment: @ tahara: I understand now. And can duplicate your results (in IE9). Very strange! I updated the text of the question and added some links to live versions of the code.

Comment: Fascinating, it's the `append` that causes the trouble. If you just hook up the event (but don't do the `append`), you can use `Ctrl+Z` on IE. If you use a timer instead of an event, doing the `append` if you see the value change, *that* prevents `Ctrl+Z` from working. So it really is the `append`. Bizarre.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846516/undo-ctrl-z-is-not-working-for-text-area-when-i-use-jquery-autocomplete-in-i . It seems that if you update visual elements on a page, the history of textboxes resets. IE bug

Comment: But I was specific issues IE! And I do not like this solution. In order to confirm the topic of the past were more firmly. I am sorry. And thank you.